# Number of coprime pairs in a given segment

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for an efficient algorithm that given two positive integers `n` and `m`, finds the number of coprime pairs `(x,y)` such that `1 <= x <= n` and `1 <= y <= m`. Any ideas?

Comment: and by efficient, I mean something better than O(n^2)

Comment: sorry, I meant better than O(nm)

Comment: Do you want to count distinct ordered pairs, or distinct two-element sets?  In other words, do you want to count both (1, 2) and (2, 1)?  And for that matter, do you want to count pairs where 1 is one of the elements?

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for ordered pairs. (1,2) and (2,1) are two different pairs. I also want to count the pairs where 1 is included.

Comment: I'd say you want a variant on the answer given [here](http://www.quora.com/How-many-relatively-prime-number-pairs-are-there-in-a-given-range).  I think that would be `O(min(n, m))` if you can compute the Mobius function in O(1) (e.g. from a table).  If you need to tabulate the values of the Mobius function yourself, then that will dominate the asymptotic complexity, and I'm not sure you end up better than O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a ternary tree to generate the coprimes? Something like

```
def gen_coprimes(max_m, max_n):
    t1 = [(2,1)]
    t2 = [(3,1)]
    b1 = lambda m,n:(2*m-n, m)
    b2 = lambda m,n:(2*m+n, m)
    b3 = lambda m,n:(m+2*n, n)
    while t1 or t2:
        yield from t1
        yield from t2
        t1 = [(i,j) for i,j in (f(m,n) for m,n in t1 for f in (b1,b2,b3)) if i<max_m and j<max_n]
        t2 = [(i,j) for i,j in (f(m,n) for m,n in t2 for f in (b1,b2,b3)) if i<max_m and j<max_n]
```

`list(gen_coprimes(5,6))` gives `[(2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3)]`.

Should be somewhere around O(n). Correct me if I'm wrong though, still getting a handle on this big O notation stuff. Algorithm from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Generating_all_coprime_pairs

Comment: *Generating* all the pairs cannot have asymptotic complexity better than O(nm) because the number of pairs is o(nm).  A more efficient solution than that needs to count the number of pairs without actually generating them.